# Input position doesn't display properly on Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, input

I am get stuck with input form. When I check it in developer console all is ok. But when I check it from my iphone it change position to 1-2px approximately. I check it from android phone with same sizes and all is ok. 
Input on Iphone 5 in dev console - http://cs629525.vk.me/v629525181/40c5e/zrdadYwKeBU.jpg .
Input from my iphone 5s - http://cs629525.vk.me/v629525181/40c57/KjsRhwnjQ4k.jpg .
Code below

```
<form id="subscribe">
            <input type="text" class="enter-email" name="subscribe-email" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" spellcheck="false" />
            <button type="submit" id="signup-button" class="signup-button c-form">NOTIFY ME</button>
            <label for="subscribe-email" class="subscribe-message c-form"></label>
        </form>
<!--css-->
.enter-email {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 17.5%;
width: 40%;
font-size: 16px;
height: 50px;
background: none;
border: 2px solid white;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}

.signup-button {
height: 50px;
border: 2px solid white;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
width: 25%;
background: #32dbd0;
margin-left: -6px;
transition: all 0.4s ease;}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
padding: 1px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your two elements:

```
.enter-email {
    vertical-align: top;
    ...
}

.signup-button {
    vertical-align: top;
    ...
}
```

Buttons and inputs are by default inline-blocks. That will force them to be aligned at the same level.